# Is it possible to create connection (websocket?) from mobile phone to java on desktop?

Tags: java, android, browser

I would like to send data directly from my Android phone to Java in the web browser on my desktop. Both devices may not be on the same subnet. Is it actually possible, or do the both devices first need to connect to a common server on the Internet that relays the data between two [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)?

Comment: are you really running ajva in the browser? or is it javascript?

Comment: What does browser extension run? Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Since both applications (browser + app) are both websocket clients, you need a third application acting as the websocket
server. This third application has to offer the websocket(s) that both applications connect to `ws://third-app/socket`.

If this app is running locally in your network or on a server on the Internet is up to you. But if both devices are in different subnets your firewalls/routers have to ensure that both devices can reach the websocket server.

Comment: I think that most browsers can receive Firebase Cloud Messages. So if it is not websocket, could I use FCM to send small amount of data from mobile directly to browser without any (other than FCM) third server?

Comment: FCM was build to send notifications to mobile devices. But you can also send notifications to the browser.
It was not build to transfer lots of data between devices. If it fits your use-case give it a try.

Comment: By the way, when Whatsapp web communicates with Whatsapp on mobile, I do not think it goes over some 3rd party server. It seems to me that by pairing over QR code some kind of p2p authorization and connection is estabilished and then when mobile device receives the message, it is send from mobile straight to browser session. I only think so, I can't prove it.